# Why are Java classes of a specific Flutter package not being found when executing flutter run

Tags: java, android, flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to execute a Flutter project locally as I have connected my mobile device with my laptop. When I do `flutter run` it runs for a while and then it crashes with the following

```
/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location/MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:21: error: cannot find
symbol
[        ]     private FlutterLocationService locationService;
[        ]             ^
[        ]   symbol:   class FlutterLocationService
[        ]   location: class MethodCallHandlerImpl
```

This is a repeated problem with almost all the other classes in the location-4.4.0 folder. I have tried deleting the folder and reinstalling the project packages and dependencies, I have tried running the command on VSCode and on terminal but in both cases the same error appears and I have also tried playing around with the cache and pub-cache of flutter and still it hasn't fixed the issue as it keeps getting reproduced.

Comment: That's an odd error, the FlutterLocationService.kt and the MethodCallHandlerImpl.java sit right next to each other in the same folder: https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/tree/d00c096953c9442a86e35f2c3611cd83022aca9b/packages/location/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location - could it be that your build somehow doesn't support kotlin?

Comment: @zapl I don't think so. I installed kotlin either way but it doesn't seem to make a difference. The folder structure is also the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, so I fixed it with this command in the terminal.

```
flutter clean  
flutter pub get
```